# Electron-builder Tray Icon not showing up (Linux Mint 20, electronjs 11, electron-builder 22)

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-builder, trayicon

So i have this very simple electron.js test-project which works fine with npm start:

```
const { app, nativeImage } = require('electron');
const electron = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const Tray = electron.Tray
const iconpath = path.join(__dirname, './logo_transparent_white_512x512.png')


app.on('ready', function(){
  icon = nativeImage.createFromPath(iconpath);
  icon = icon.resize({ width: 16, height: 16})
  new Tray(icon);
  console.log('ready');
})
```

The package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "electronbuilder",
  "version": "1.0.2",
  "description": "dadlu",
  "main": "main.js",
  "homepage": "www.test.com",
  "dependencies": {
    "path": "^0.12.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^11.1.1",
    "electron-builder": "^22.9.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "dist": "electron-builder"
  },
  "author": "test-author",
  "license": "ISC",
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.elecctron.builder",
    "productName": "testBuild",
    "linux": {
      "target": [
        "deb"
      ],
      "maintainer": "test-maintainer",
    },
    "deb": {
      "depends": [
        "libappindicator1",
        "libnotify4"
      ]
    },
    "extraFiles": [
      "./logo_transparent_white_512x512.png"
    ]
  }
}
```

After running:

```
yarn dist
```

and waiting a minute, I can install the package. But running it doesn't do anything.
when enabling the console ('add to desktop', 'open with Text Editor', 'Terminal=true') I can observe, that the app started successfully:
[console.log('ready') got executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYBT1.png)

I tried all sorts of ways to get the tray icon to work, stubbing across the weirdest things. F.e. when building the Icon like this:

```
tray = new Tray(./logo_transparent_white_512x512.png);
```

it does work with npm start, but after yarn dist, nothing happends. Though, going into the applications folder and running

```
$ ./{name}
```

it starts up fine, including the tray icon. (./logo_transparent_white_512x512.png isn't 512x512, i already resized it to 256x256)

its cant be an lib problem either, because [this](https://gist.github.com/bellbind/f65f78a35bbbd4917a8ae4a6b18c5012) project can be build fine on my system.

I hope someone can help me, ive got my first real project ready, but can only start it with npm start. Any attempts to build it fail, meaning the tray icon doesn't show up.

If some information is missing, feel free to ask.